# How to find a word(string) in Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to check if my array has the word

This is my code please help

```js
    var name = ['heine', 'hans'];
    var password = ['12343', '1234'];
    function login() {
    var pos;
        if(name.includes('hans')) {
            console.log("enthält");
            pos = name.indexOf('hans');
            console.log(pos)
            if(password[pos] === '1234') {
                console.log("angemeldet")
            }
        }
      }
```

consoleout = 6, but why, it must be a 1

If the word `hans` is in the array, than i need the position from the word in the array

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Terrible idea, in relation to authentication on the frontend, but from a mental exercise standpoint, you are asking about `indexOf()`

Comment: `password[i] === 1234` will however always be false, due to the passwords being strings and the usage of `===`

Comment: It is returning 6 because apparently it's thinking `name` is a string.  Which is very odd.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) handy for this. It will pass the index into the callback which you can use to find the corresponding value from the `passwords` array:

```js
function test(name, pw) {
  let names = ["heine", "hans"];
  let passwords = ["12343", "1234"];
  // is there `some` name/pw combinations that matches?
  return names.some((n, index) => name == n && pw == passwords[index])
}

console.log(test("hans", '1234'))   // true
console.log(test("hans", '12345'))  // false
console.log(test("hans", '12343'))  // false

console.log(test("heine", '12343')) // true
console.log(test("mark", '12343'))  // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this. I am not sure if it is what you want.

```
let names = ["heine", "hans"];
let password = ["12343", "1234"];
let i, temp;

function log(login, pass) {
    if((i = names.indexOf(login)) !== -1){
        if(password[i] === pass)
            console.log("Logged!");
    }
}

log("hans", "1234")
```

Comment: i think it need a for-loop, i just add it now an test it

Comment: `code` var name = ["heine", "hans"];
var password = ["12343", "1234"];
var i, temp;

function login(login, pass) {
    console.log("start")
    for(temp = 0; temp < name.length; temp++) {
        console.log(temp)
        if((i = name.indexOf(login)) !== -1){
            console.log("name")
            if(password[temp] === pass)
                console.log("Logged!");
        }
    }
}

login("hans", "1234")

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can also try something like this with [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const usernames = ['heine', 'hans'];
const passwords = ['12343', '1234'];

function login(user, pass)
{
    let userIdx = usernames.findIndex(x => x === user);

    // On a real application do not give any tip about which is
    // wrong, just return "invalid username or password" on both cases.
    
    if (userIdx < 0)
        return "Invalid username!";

    if (pass !== passwords[userIdx])
        return "Invalid password!";

    return "Login OK!"
}

console.log(login("heine", "12343"));
console.log(login("hans", "lala"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is name is window.name which is a string..

```js
var name = ['heine', 'hans'];
console.log(window.name, typeof window.name)

var xname = ['heine', 'hans'];
console.log(window.xname, typeof window.xname)
```

Change your variable to another word that is not reserved if you are in global scope.